# Rendering spaces at end of spans without changing line breaks

Tags: html, css

I am needing to style sequences of characters in a single paragraph e.g.

```html
<span style="color:red">hello </span><span style="color:blue">world</span>
```

The paragraph of text flows across multiple lines. The issue is that the spaces at the end of spans are not rendered by browsers and the solutions to force them to display, changes how the lines break. This means that when the text is coloured differently at different positions, words jump from one line to another which isn't acceptable in this app.

The two methods I have tried for displaying terminating spaces that both change line breaks are:

1. replace terminating spaces with nbsp `"\u00a0"`

Although this renders the spaces, it means that it changes how rows break across lines.

2. replace terminating spaces with single space spans that use `white-space: pre` style

This also renders spaces but causes similar disruption to line breaks.

Is there anything else I can try that will not change line breaks?

Comment: I see the spaces in my browser (Chrome) when I run it locally. I took the liberty of putting a Stack Snippet so that, if you click Run code snippet, you can see whether you see the space or not in your browser.

Comment: Same here, in multiple browsers on multiple OSes. Or did you mean something else? Maybe spaces at the end of a line are not rendered?